# Drools Decision Table using in and not in for same column

Tags: drools, redhat, business-rules, drools-guvnor

I'm working on POC using Drools decision table - Drools 6.5.4. I have a scenario where for one column i want to use both in and not in at same time.

Example :-

listOfApples in ("Apple","Banana")

listOfApples not in ("Apple","Orange")

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer . Tried this and it is working fine

ContainsString  $param

not in ('A')|

in ('A','B')|

in ('C','D')|

Answer (score 0):

You should use two columns, one for the condition where the operator "in" is used and the other one for "not in". By entering the list in the right column, the decision is made between these two operators. An entry would be a list of strings, inserted via `$param`:

```
someString in ($param)  | someString not in ($param) 
...                     |
"Apple", "Banana"       |
                        | "Lemon", "Orange"
```